# Is it possible to run a bookmarklet on Chrome by selecting it from the bookmark?

Tags: chrome-for-android, bookmarklets

I am using Chrome for Android. If I have a bookmarklet saved as a bookmark, then I am able to run it by:

1. Typing its name in the address bar until it shows.
2. Clicking the upward-leftward pointing diagonal arrow next to it to load it into the address bar.
3. Clicking enter.

I am *not* able to run a bookmarklet that I have saved as a bookmark by:

1. Opening Chrome's vertically-aligned three-dot menu.
2. Selecting `Bookmarks`.
3. Navigating to the bookmarklet's entry.
4. Clicking the entry.

I don't want to run my bookmarklets using the first method. I want to run them by going to them in the bookmarks menu (like the second method). If I click any other bookmark in the bookmarks menu, Chrome will navigate to the page. I expect to be able to run bookmarklets from the bookmarks menu.

Is it possible to run a bookmarklet on Chrome by selecting it from the bookmark?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Either wait for the Chrome for Android team to fix it or find a browser which supports it.

I found this issue ticket for Chromium (base code of Chrome/Chrome for Android/ChromeOS) which was opened in 2015 for the Android platform:

[Issue 480010: Enhanced bookmarks do not support javascript bookmarklets](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=480010&q=OS%3DAndroid%20bookmarklet&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

The gist is that:

> This is tricky because on phones BookmarkActivity sends intent to Chrome to launch the bookmarked url, and currently ChromeLauncherActivity rejects javascript urls.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=480010#c11

Based on [older](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=480010#c7) [comments](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=480010#c8) the bookmarklet feature existed in a prior version, but disabled since then.

Answer (score 0):

I have found selecting the bookmark does work on another Android browser - Firefox. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Well, that's not Chrome, so that's not an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/257906)

Answer (score -1):

Chrome Android doesn't let you run Bookmarklets the traditional way, But, there is a workaround, you can call Bookmarklet from the address bar, Below Tutorial might be helpful.

https://paul.kinlan.me/use-bookmarklets-on-chrome-on-android/

Comment: FWIW, this is already mentioned in the question.