# JavaScript bookmarklets not executing in Android Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android, javascript, bookmarklets

I know that Javascript bookmarlets work in Android Chrome as I did see
them working before, but today for some reason they don't.

I installed Android Firefox, and they work there. I have reviewed site settings on Android Chrome and it does say "allow Javascript" there. I have also tried running it as a "Desktop site" and it still does not work. It also does not seem to matter whether "Safe browsing" is enabled or not. It still does not work.

Gotta wonder why.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is it possible to run a bookmarklet on Chrome by selecting it from the bookmark?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209456/44325)